# Android in app Billing to Unlock all Features

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I followed a guide to enter the in app purchase and unlock all features. The procedure to purchase works well. 
I explain what I do: I added a check in my database, which counts the number of records in a table, if the number is> = 1, I open an activity for purchase in the app. Once purchased, through the method getPurchases, control the purchase, if it was done I open the activity, otherwise I open the activity for purchase. I created this code peril control but I get error:

```
08-11 18:08:18.120: W/ContextImpl(19293): Implicit intents with startService
 are not safe: Intent {
 act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND }
 android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:529
 main.Elenco_F_Fragment.Controlla_record_per_acquisto:243
 main.Elenco_F_Fragment.access$9:233
```

this is the row 243:

```
final boolean blnBind = getActivity().bindService(new Intent(
                "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

this is the code for the control

```
private void Controlla_record_per_acquisto(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String controllo = "SELECT COUNT(_id) FROM tbf";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(controllo, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        int numero_id = c.getInt(0);            

    if(numero_id >=1){  
        // Bind Service
        final boolean blnBind = getActivity().bindService(new Intent(
                "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if (!blnBind) return;
        if (mService == null) return;
        Bundle ownedItems;


        try {
            ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getActivity().getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
            Intent intent = null;
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Crea_e.class); 
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(context, "getPurchases - fail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w(tag, "getPurchases() - fail!");
            return;
        }

        int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        Toast.makeText(context, "getPurchases() - \"RESPONSE_CODE\" return " + String.valueOf(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(tag, "getPurchases() - \"RESPONSE_CODE\" return " + String.valueOf(response));

        if (response != 0) return;

        ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
        ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

        Log.i(tag, "getPurchases() - \"INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST\" return " + ownedSkus.toString());
        Log.i(tag, "getPurchases() - \"INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST\" return " + purchaseDataList.toString());
        Log.i(tag, "getPurchases() - \"INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE\" return " + (signatureList != null ? signatureList.toString() : "null"));
        Log.i(tag, "getPurchases() - \"INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN\" return " + (continuationToken != null ? continuationToken : "null"));


    }else   {       
        Intent intent = null;               
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT--------------------------------------------

```
private void Controlla_record_per_acquisto(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String controllo = "SELECT COUNT(_id) FROM FTB";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(controllo, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        int numero_id = c.getInt(0);            

    if(numero_id >=1){  
        Intent intent = null;               
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);  


    }else   {       
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Cure.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the new Billing system, with the `IabHelper` class there you can do what you have described above both async/sync without the needs for "extra" code really.

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Comment: I followed this guide: [http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial] updated and it easier than yours. It works well, but I still have to do the check in the query, count records, if the user has already made ​​the purchase I have to open another activity. how can I?

Comment: You can asynchronously fetch all the purchases that the user has, for example when the app starts, then you can store them in sharedpreferences. This is how I do it and it works very well.

Under "Query Purchased items" -> http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html

Comment: yes, but in that case if you uninstall and then install again?

Comment: Since you query the inventory upon app launch the sharedpreferences will be updated each time the app is launched, including when the user reinstalls.